# Memory leak in Websphere 7 + EJB3, a lot of instances of ClassMapping

Tags: java, orm, memory-leaks, websphere, openjpa

sorry for my english, I speak spanish.
I recently migrate an application from ejb 2.x to ejb3 (approx. 300 entities), Im using WebSphere 7.0.0.9.

After 10 hours of work, the system crash with an OutOfMemoryError.

Analyzing the coredump, I see a lot of instance of the org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping class (please see the attached a screenshot).

[alt text http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/7273/phd2jdbccfg.png](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/7273/phd2jdbccfg.png)

I believe that the culprit is the list of ValueListeners of the Value class, but I'm not sure, and I dont know how to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Contact the support, open a case.

Comment: In my case, these solution involve a lot of burocracy :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install latest WebSphere Application Server [fix pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029634). We have encoutered a similar issue related to OpenJPA and updating the server solved the problem.